# Why does JDBC use primitives instead of wrapper clasess?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

*This isn't a specific problem I'm having now, just something I can't wrap my head around. I couldn't find any questions here or info on the internet about this.*

Wrapper classes such as `java.lang.Integer` (for the primitive `int`) have existed in Java since the start. But the developers of **JDBC** chose to implement methods such as `getInt` and `getLong` using Java primitives. The problem with primitives is that they cannot represent SQL `NULL`.

To workaround this problem, JDBC developers wrote many methods to return *default* primitive values such as `0` and `false` when the column is `NULL`, and introduced a `wasNull()` function for users to check if it was supposed to be `null`. What's worse is when many other methods such as *PreparedStatement's* `setInt` accept primitives instead of wrapper objects, and users have to conditionally use `setNull` to set the corresponding column to `NULL`.

I find that this has added unnecessary complexity to how the **JDBC** API is to be used by its users. If JDBC's *ResultSet* object had `getInteger` returning Java `null` as an *Integer object* when the column had SQL `NULL`, it would have been very convenient without the hassle of checking `wasNull`. Java's unboxing would automatically take care of cases where the *Integer* object has to be assigned to an `int` primitive variable, converting it to `0`. If *PreparedStatement* has a `setInteger` method, the users can simply use this to set the value for a suitable column - including an SQL `NULL` value - without the hassle of checking whether it should be null and reverting to `setNull`.

Even until now, there was no change made to the JDBC to correct this anomaly. JDBC continues to use primitive types even after we are already at Java 1.7 or 1.8 *(Am I right?)*. Java's built-in boxing and unboxing would have ensured that old applications written assuming primitive types would continue to work correctly with a version of JDBC updated to use wrappers. **So why has no one bothered to upgrade the JDBC to use wrapper objects in place of primitives?**

**PS:** It would be nice to hear recommended alternative solutions to this nonsensical problem with JDBC.

Comment: Don't forget that boxing/unboxing was introduced relatively late. Java 5 ?

Comment: Was it only Java 5? Even then, the JDBC API could have been updated and taken advantage of autoboxing to take care of compatibility issues.

Comment: Just use `Integer columnName = (Integer) resultSet.getObject("columnName")`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on programmers.

Comment: Please allow it to brew here before moving it to Programmers.SE, if you vote to do so. :)

Comment: You are aware that you can simply call `setObject`, so your example for setting null is not really an issue at all, only retrieval can be considered slightly bothersome. And besides, 'good' database designs don't allow NULL ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it doesn't entirely answer your question, the JDBC 1.2 specification contains the following ['rejected' design choice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame15.html#20169):

> A.8 Support for GetObject versus getXXX
>   Because of the overlap between the various get/set methods and the generic getObject/setObject methods we looked at discarding our get/set methods and simply using getObject/setObject. However for the simple common cases where a programmer know the SQL types, the resulting casts and extracts are extremely tedious:
>   `int i = ((Integer)r.getObject(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER)).intValue()`
>   We therefore decided to bend our minimalist principles a little in this case and retain the various get/set methods as the preferred interface for the majority of applications programmers, while also adding the getObject/setObject methods for tool builders and sophisticated applications

[Chapter 14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame14.html#50686) of that spec also says:

> For example, a SQL INTEGER is normally mapped to a Java int. This supports a simple interface for reading and writing SQL values as simple Java types.

And [Chapter 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame2.html) says:

> Provide a Java interface that is consistent with the rest of the Java system

And as far as I can tell most of the Java API uses primitive types instead of the wrapper types.

Also around the time of the spec (1.2 is dated January 10, 1997), there was no boxing and unboxing, and using `Integer` etc was rather cumbersome. For example you simply can't do math with `Integer` directly, you first need to call `intValue()` to obtain an `int` before you can actually do any basic operation like addition, multiplication etc, and then you would need to convert the result back to an `Integer` to store it. That sounds like a very good reason to have getters and setters for the primitives.

And please remember the spec was designed somewhere between 1995 and 1997, an era where memory was relatively more expensive and wrapper objects for primitives simply cost more memory. I believe a simple object is 8 bytes + the size of the primitive field. For an `int` that is a cost of 12 bytes instead of 4.

Comment: Thank you; good research work. Your answer provides some reasonable arguments - the note about memory cost is particularly interesting. `:)`

Comment: @ADTC consider accepting the answer if the answer is satisfying

Answer (score 3):

In a word - *compatability*.  The JDBC API was published long before autoboxing and changing it now would require all 3rd party vendors to update and release their JDBC implementations - a logistical nightmare, if it were even possible plus those using the JDBC API would have to accomodate any changes in behaviour.

The obvious way to make a change of this type would be to release a new API, JDBC2 if you will, though IMHO JDBC is so broken as to warrant this, especially given that JPA/Hibernate hides the low level JDBC API in most common usages.

Comment: Even then, the JDBC API could have been updated and taken advantage of autoboxing to take care of compatibility issues. I'm sure the big names like Oracle would have updated their implementations, but those unwilling to update could still continue to work, right? (Although that will understandably introduce false expectations). Besides, why wasn't JDBC extended to provide wrapper support **alongside** primitive support, allowing vendors a choice in implementing it?

Comment: It's just not possible without changing the existing interface or the description of how it works - for example, if `ResultSet.getInt` were changed to return an `java.lang.Integer` and could reuturn `null` when the underlying column value was `null` code that relied on *autoboxing* to convert the returned `java.lang.Integer` to a primative would start throwing `NullPointerException`s when a `null` was incountered.  The best you could do would be to introduce a `java.sql.ResultSet2` but like I said, I suspect that's overkill for the problem in hand.